# Show decimal places intelligently?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to display decimal places intelligently (i.e. without having to choose between lengthy decimal places or a ton of trailing zeroes) in JavaScript. This is my original list:

```
6
8
12.225252
```

Currently I'm using `toFixed(1)`, and have output like this:

```
6.0
8.0
12.2
```

Is there a way I can get:

```
6
8
12.2
```

instead? Obviously I can write some custom code to do this, but is there anything in-built in JavaScript?

Comment: So you want Javascript to read your mind at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.round`.

```
function roundTo(n, decimals) {
    var d = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(n * d)/d;
}
```

Examples:

```
roundTo(6, 1)
6
roundTo(8, 1)
8
roundTo(12.623456, 1)
12.6
```

Comment: @Richard, why exactly did you unaccept the answer? Does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see whether the floor of the value is the same as the value itself:

```
if (Math.floor(x) === x) {
  // no fractional part
}
```

Realize that floating point numbers are tricky and irritating, so you may end up with fractional parts in cases where, purely mathematically, you don't expect them.

*edit* also of course this won't help much with "6.001".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a function to Number prototype like this:

```
Number.prototype.toFixedIfDecimal = function(places){
  var isWhole_re = /^\s*\d+\s*$/;
  if(String(this).search(isWhole_re) != -1)
    return this;
  else
    return this.toFixed(places);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var myNumber1 = 8;
var myNumber2 = 10.512;
alert(myNumber1.toFixedIfDecimal(1)); // will return 8
alert(myNumber2.toFixedIfDecimal(1)); // will return 10.5
```